# Indefinite Integral of $ \ln(x)^{\ln(x)^{\ln(x)^{.^{.^{.^{\ln(x)}}}}}}$ for an $ n $-number of $ \ln(x) $'s with respect to $ x $

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, tetration

This is tetration question about finding the indefinite integral. I am not sure where to start so any help would be appreciated.

$$ I= \int \ln(x)^{\ln(x)^{\ln(x)^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\ln(x)}}}}}} dx $$

Comment: With one $\ln$ this is well known.  Now do it with two $\ln$s before asking us the general question.

Comment: I am aware of how to approach those but not this one. @GEdgar

Comment: I assume that $\ln(x)^{\ln(x)}$ is $(\ln x)^{\ln x}$, right? The entire logarithm is the base of the power, not just $x$, isn't it?

Comment: yes that is correct @ΒασίληςΜάρκος

Comment: A very personal opinion :  tetration issues haven't a wide interest ; you **never** encounter them in applied mathematics and in "pure mathematics", they are not connected to other branches.

Answer (score 2):

*These are less of an answer and more of a set of thoughts for a specific case of the problem.*

For $n=2$:
$$\begin{align*}
\int (\ln x)^{\ln x}dx&\overset{x=e^y}{\underset{dx=e^ydy}{=}}\int y^ye^ydy=\tag{$\star$}\\
&=\int e^{y\ln y}e^ydy=\\
&=\int e^{y\ln y+y}dy=\\
&=\int\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(y\ln y+y)^k}{k!}=\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\int(y\ln y+y)^kdy=\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\int\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}y^n\ln^nyy^{k-n}dy=\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\int y^k\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}\ln^nydy=\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}\int y^k\ln^nydy
\end{align*}$$
I introduced power series since I think that integrals of the form $\int x^xdx$ cannot be calculated in terms of "simple" functions.

Now, if one would like to procceed to further calculations, I feel that we should talk about definite integrals. However, one can calculate the integral: $$I_{n,k}=\int y^k\ln^nydy$$
by applying multiple times integration by parts:
$$I_{n,k}=\frac{y^{k+1}}{k+1}\ln^ny-\frac{n}{k+1}I_{n-1,k}+c$$

However, when $n>2$, I cannot find something as "straightforward" as the above proccedure...